# How to make a JPanel inside a JFrame fill the whole window?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

In the below example, how can I get the JPanel to take up all of the JFrame? I set the preferred size to 800x420 but it only actually fills 792x391.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BSTest extends JFrame {
    BufferStrategy bs;
    DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();

    public BSTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());   // edited line
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800,420);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        bs = getBufferStrategy();
        panel.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,420));
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);     // edited line
        panel.drawStuff();
    }

    public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void drawStuff() {
            while(true) {
                try {
                    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bs.getDrawGraphics();
                    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    System.out.println("W:"+getSize().width+", H:"+getSize().height);
                    g.fillRect(0,0,getSize().width,getSize().height);
                    bs.show();
                    g.dispose();
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                } catch (Exception e) { System.exit(0); }
            }
        }
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BSTest bst = new BSTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Swing engine has its own paint loop, you don't need while(true).  Just override `JComponent.paint(Graphics g)` in your panel class

Comment: Hi @Joe, I'm trying to use `BufferStrategy` here for which you dont use `paint()`, thats why the `while()` loop and what the `setIgnoreRepaint(true);` are for. Any idea about how I can fill the whole window by any chance?

Comment: Yes, try passing your JPanel to `JFrame.setContentPane()`

Answer (score 6):

If you are having only one panel in frame and nothing else then try this:

- Set BorderLayout in frame.
- Add panel in frame with BorderLayout.CENTER

---

May be this is happening because of while loop in JPanel.(Not sure why? finding actual reason. Will update when find it.) If you replace it with `paintComponent(g)` method all works fine:

```
public BSTest() {
    //--- your code as it is
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //-- removed panel.drawStuff();
}

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        System.out.println("W:" + getSize().width + ", H:" + getSize().height);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    }
 }

//your code as it is.
```

Comment: Hi @Harry, I've just tried your suggestion (see new *edited lines* in code above) but it displays exactly the same!

Comment: thanks but I'm trying to make a game using `BufferStrategy` here for which you don't use `paintComponent`, you first draw the stuff and then you flip the buffer over using `bs.show()`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative using pack instead.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PackExample extends JFrame {

    public PackExample(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        panel.setBackground(Color.green);
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
     new PackExample();
   }

}
```

Comment: +1 for `pack()`; -1 for using `setPreferredSize()` [incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).

Comment: @trashgod  DYM 1) Use an advanced layout (AKA the 'kleopatra method') 2) Override `getPreferredSize()` 3) Something else?  Since 1) requires 3rd party layouts, it cannot be done in core J2SE (which may or may not be a problem) 2) Makes the preferred size of the component inflexible.  I would prefer setting the size just as jtp did.  +1

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thank you for elaborating. I meant 2) override [`getPreferredSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize%28%29) in the sense shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9447425/230513) and mentioned in bullet one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229662/230513). I see an unexplained `setPreferredSize()` as potentially misleading in this context.  It depends on what's _in_ the panel: more components → `setPreferredSize()` bad;  just painting → `setPreferredSize()` OK.

Comment: @trashgod Thanks for clarifying.  After glancing at the OP's code (& seeing the `BufferStrategy`) I decided there was almost 0 chance of anything but 'just painting'.  However now I think about it, for 'just painting',  a `JComponent` is usually sufficient.  Also the word 'unexplained' suggests the answer might be edited with a code comment to make the context clear.

Answer (score 3):

This took me forever to figure out but its actually the simplest code ever. 
Just create a parent panel and pass GridLayout then add your child panel like this.

```
JPanel parentPanel= new JPanel(new GridLyout());
JPanel childPanel= new JPanel();
parentPanel.add(childPanel);
```

Comment: Seems that the FlowLayout used by default tries to squish everything as small as it can. Even a BorderLayout solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the JFrame with the whole of JPanel you need to setUndecorated to true i.e.  `frame.setUndecorated(true);`. But now you have to worry about your MAXIMIZE< MINIMIZE, and CLOSE Buttons, towards the top right side(Windows Operating System)