# Swing setResizable and setBounds

Tags: java, swing

Hello I am working on my swing based gui part of my project and I need to synchronize the setBounds JFrame's method with the setResizable call so I do this:

```
    setResizable(true);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(screenSize.width/2 - screenSize.width/4,  screenSize.height/2 - screenSize.height/4, screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    setBounds(rect);
    setResizable(false);
```

but the result is that my frame doesn't get the given bounds it just disable the resize functionality. If I remove the last setResizable call then the form will get the right bounds. Actually I have an wizard which is based on an frame and many panels, I change the panels on the frame like states. Only in one panel I would like to give to user the opportunity to resize the frame otherwise it should be in fixed size. So in my main frame I implemented two methods, enableWizardMode and enablePlayingGameMode :

```
    @Override
    public void enablePlayingGameMode() {
setResizable(true);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  
        setBounds(new Rectangle(screenSize.width/10, screenSize.height/10, screenSize.width - screenSize.width/5, screenSize.height- screenSize.height/5));
    }

    @Override
    public void enableWizardMode() {
setResizable(true);
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  
        setBounds(new Rectangle(screenSize.width/2 - screenSize.width/4, screenSize.height/2 - screenSize.height/4, screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2));
setResizable(false);
    }
```

I tried with the IComponentListener but it doesn't help me it resized my frame randomly.
Also I tried with SwingUtilities.invokeLater in order to set the resizable flag to false, but it doesn't help too. 
Does anybody know the solution of this problem?? I running Linux and oracle jdk7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting preferredSize along with calling `pack()` has always worked well for me.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SizeFoo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(screenSize.width / 2 - screenSize.width
            / 4, screenSize.height / 2 - screenSize.height / 4,
            screenSize.width / 2, screenSize.height / 2);
      System.out.println("rect: " + rect);
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(rect.width, rect.height));
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocation(rect.x, rect.y);
      //frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      System.out.println("JFrame size:" + frame.getSize());
   }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I just tried it. Actually I have an wizard which is based on an frame and many panels, I change the panels on the frame like states. Only in one panel I would like to give to user the opportunity to resize the frame otherwise it should not be resizable.

Comment: @AlexTheo: Then you need to update your question and give all pertinent information including this and more details. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) much like my post above which will allow us to see your problem for ourselves and allow us to modify and test working code.

Comment: @AlexTheo: Thanks for the additional info, but again if you can, try to create a ***small*** compilable and runnable program, an [sscce](http://sscce.org) (please check the link) that demonstrates the problem as that will make it much easier for us to solve. It kind of depends on how important this question is to you and how quickly you need it answered. If it's not that important, than ignore this suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @Hovercraft and shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118753/230513) and discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513), you should `pack()` your enclosing `Window`, relying on the preferred size of the components. It may happen that your project contains a dominant display panel that contains no other components and has no intrinsic, preferred size. In that case, override `getPreferredSize()` and return a `Dimension` that reflects the fraction(s) of the screen indicated in your question.